# Spring Cloud Consul dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Trying out Spring Cloud Consul(http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/) however I am running into issues with dependencies. Gradle is reporting that the artifacts dont exist:

```
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-consul-all/1.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-starter-consul-all-1.0.0.M1.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-consul-all/1.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-starter-consul-all-1.0.0.M1.jar]
```

I browsed under http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud and tried to add cloud-consul and other repos but they seem to generating more build errors.

Comment: It looks like their web page is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The starters are not part of 1.0.0.M1, they will be part of 1.0.0.M2.  You can find them in the [snapshot repo](http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local/org/springframework/cloud/).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your config to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-consul:1.0.0.M1'
}repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
}
```